# Command to add an entry in to top of the /etc/hosts file

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I do have a Windows command to append (postpend) an entry into `/etc/hosts` file:

```
echo 10.0.0.1 example.com >> %WinDir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

I need the entry to be *prepended* to the hosts file.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756071/prepend-to-the-beginning-of-the-first-line-of-a-file

Comment: Why would you need to prepend it in the hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

As a PowerShell script.

Add the prepend as a string with newline together with contents of hosts file then output the file as ANSI

```powershell
$Prepend = "10.0.0.1  example.com"
$Path = "$env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
($Prepend | Out-String) + (get-content $Path | Out-String ) | Out-File $Path -Encoding Default
```